# como concatenar variables en javascript

Tags: javascript

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buen día , alguien de ustedes como puedo concatenar  mis variables nomTem, tituTem, uniMedTem y perTem ? se los agradeceria, ya que necesito tenerlos en un sola linea para mostrarlo al momento de imprimirlo , pero solo quiero saber como se concatena Saludos.

```
   function nomTituloTem(idO){
   var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedorMapaPrint");
   mapasTemObjImp = $.grep(mapasTemObj, function (t){
    return t.id == idO
   });

    var nomTem = document.createElement('div');
    nomTem.innerHTML = mapasTemObjImp[0].nombre;
    contenedor.appendChild(nomTem);

    var tituTem = document.createElement('div');
    tituTem.innerHTML = mapasTemObjImp[0].titulo;
    contenedor.appendChild(tituTem);

    var uniMedTem = document.createElement('div');
    uniMedTem.innerHTML = mapasTemObjImp[0].unidadMedida;
    contenedor.appendChild(uniMedTem);

    var perTem = document.createElement('div');
    perTem.innerHTML = mapasTemObjImp[0].periodo;
    contenedor.appendChild(perTem);


       }
```

Comment: No se entiende demasiado bien lo que quieres conseguir. Esas variables contienen elementos **HTML**. ¿A qué te refieres con concatenarlas?

Comment: bueno a lo mejor lo tengo mal , pero lo que pasa es que , al final me regresa informacion de mapastemobjimp[0] , pero como esta en diferentes divs sale uno en cada renglon , lo que quiero es que esten todos los div en uno solo, o si se puede poner todo en solo div , para que se vea visualmente en un solo renglon y asi.

Comment: ¿Y qué es lo que te trae `mapasTemObjImp[0]`? Si subes un pantallazo del resultado podríamos entender el problema que te has encontrado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esto:

```
function nomTituloTem(idO){
 var contenedor = document.getElementById("contenedorMapaPrint");
 mapasTemObjImp = $.grep(mapasTemObj, function (t){
  return t.id == idO
 });

  var todo = document.createElement('div');
  var separador = ' '; //Puedes cambiarlo por un '<br/>', si quieres que salgan con saltos de linea
  //Solo tienes que ir adicionando la información a mostrar en el mismo div
  todo.innerHTML = mapasTemObjImp[0].nombre + separador + mapasTemObjImp[0].titulo + separador + mapasTemObjImp[0].unidadMedida + separador + mapasTemObjImp[0].periodo;
  contenedor.appendChild(todo);
}
```

Comment: lo aplique si me sirvió saludos crack!!

Comment: Jajaaj me alegro suerte :)